# Terraform - creating Linux and Windows VMs

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am working with Terraform to create Windows and Linux VMs in Azure.
I've been reading some documentation, and I'd like to create this structure:

```
    terraform
      main.tf
      /modules
        provider.tf
        variables.tf
        /linux_vms
          linux.tf
          variables.tf
        /windows_vms
          windows.tf
          variables.tf
```

Basically, I am expecting the main.tf file inside terraform directory will be used for both linux and windows VMs creation.
Files provider.tf and variables.tf inside /terraform/modules should also be used for linux and windows vms.

As for windows.tf and variables.tf inside windows_vms, they should only be used for creating windows vms. In the some way, files inside linux_vms, should only be used for creating linux vms.

/terraform/modules/windows_vm/windows.tf

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "this" {
  name                            = var.env_name
  location                        = var.resources_location.name
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.x.name
  network_interface_ids           = [azurerm_network_interface.this.id]
  size                            = var.size
  admin_username                  = var.user
  admin_password                  = var.pass
    
  source_image_reference {
    publisher = var.image_publisher
    offer     = var.image_offer
    sku       = var.image_sku
    version   = var.vm_image_version
  }
    
  os_disk {
    name                 = "osdisk-${var.environment_name}-${random_id.this.hex}"
    caching              = "ReadOnly"
    storage_account_type = var.resources_storage_type
    disk_size_gb         = var.vm_os_size
  }
}

...
```

/terraform/main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "x" {
  name     = "rg-${var.environment_name}"
  location = var.resources_location.name
}

...
```

Inside /terraform/modules/windows_vm directory I did this:

```
    cd /terraform/modules/windows_vm
    terraform init
    terraform workspace select test_machine
    terraform validate
```

The first 2 commands went ok.
With "terraform validate" I go errors:

```
    Error: Reference to undeclared resource
    │
    │   on windows_vm.tf line 4, in resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "this":
    │    4:   resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.x.name
    │
    │ A managed resource "azurerm_resource_group" "x" has not been declared in
    │ the root module.
```

This resource "azurerm_resource_group.x.name" is defined inside /terraform/main.tf.

But I don't know how I can tell terraform to use the general files as well: /terraform/main.tf, /terraform/modules/provider.tf, variables.tf.

Comment: Can you add to the question the way you are calling the `/terraform/main.tf` in the `/terraform/modules/windows_vm` directory?

Comment: I haven't call them. How can I do that? I am new to terraform so I'd apreciate some help please

Comment: I can't help if I only see a couple of commands, an error, and the folder structure. :) We would need to see the code so someone can answer maybe.

Comment: ok, I edited and posted the code. But I just need help to call the terraform/main.tf in the /terraform/modules/windows_vm. That is what is missing (i guess)

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy to fix. One thing to note is that you would need to define an output in the `terraform/main.tf` file so it can be referenced elsewhere. So step 1 is to define the output:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "x" {
  name     = "rg-${var.environment_name}"
  location = var.resources_location.name
}

...

output "azure_rg_name" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.x.name
}
```

This should be repeated for any other resources which you plan on referencing outside of the module. Now, in the `/terraform/modules/windows_vm`, you would then do the following:

```
module "resource_group" {
  source = "../.."

  environment_name = "someenvname"
  resources_location = {
    name = "somename"
    ...
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "this" {
  name                            = var.env_name
  location                        = var.resources_location.name
  resource_group_name             = module.resource_group.azure_rg_name
  network_interface_ids           = [azurerm_network_interface.this.id]
  size                            = var.size
  admin_username                  = var.user
  admin_password                  = var.pass


  source_image_reference {
    publisher = var.image_publisher
    offer     = var.image_offer
    sku       = var.image_sku
    version   = var.vm_image_version
  }

  os_disk {
    name                 = "osdisk-${var.environment_name}-${random_id.this.hex}"
    caching              = "ReadOnly"
    storage_account_type = var.resources_storage_type
    disk_size_gb         = var.vm_os_size
  }
}
```

If the network interface is also created in the `terraform/main.tf` then you need to repeat the same process. To read more about how to invoke modules, check the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources).

Comment: I guess I habe to replace someenvname and somename right?

Comment: Well, I guess you have a better naming convention than in my answer. :)

Comment: I am facing some issues in placing the changes in windows_vm directory. Can vyou please try to be a little more clear. I am new to this so I am not being able to implement the changes

Comment: Ok, so the changes should probably go into `windows.tf` file based on what you've shown. Additionally, you need to rerun `terraform init` in the `windows_vm` directory.

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain myself but cant I just place module "resource_group" {
  source = "../.." }? I am not understanding what do put in environment_name and name. WHat are those for?

Comment: Those are for the input variables you have defined for your module.